# Android application with API Layer is working on emulator but not on physical device during testing

Tags: android, kotlin

I have Android application that get data from API Layer currency rates and codes. Everything is working on emulator, data are coming correctly. When I'm trying to test this application on physical device data are coming from API server as http response status is 200 OK, But data are not displayed.

There are all necessary permissions in Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
```

Could you please advise what is the reason that on emulator everything is ok But on phone data from API are not displaying?

There are no any exceptions or errors regarding this issue.
I've checked http response status code several times and it is  200 OK, I see that all data are coming from server currencies rates and currencies codes.

Android version of emulator and physical device is the same Android 10.0.
My code is below:

```
interface CurrencyAPI {

    @Headers("apikey:$api_key")
    @GET("/currency_data/list")
    suspend fun getCurrencyList(
    ): CurrencyList

    @Headers("apikey:$api_key")
    @GET("/currency_data/convert?")
    suspend fun convertCurrency(
        @retrofit2.http.Query("amount") amount: Int,
        @retrofit2.http.Query("from") from: String,
        @retrofit2.http.Query("to") to: String
    ): Convert

    private companion object {
        private const val api_key = "..."
    
    }

}

val gson = GsonBuilder()
    .setLenient()
    .create()

val okHttpClient by lazy {
    OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .addInterceptor(com.kiraosapp.voyagenik.ConnectivityInterceptor())
        .build()
}

val retrofit: CurrencyAPI by lazy {
    Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://api.apilayer.com/")
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .build()
        .create(CurrencyAPI::class.java)

}

class FragmentBaseCurrencySearch : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentSearchCurrencyBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    lateinit var currencyListView: ListView
    lateinit var listAdapter: ArrayAdapter<String>
    lateinit var currencies: ArrayList<String>
    lateinit var searchView: SearchView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        _binding = FragmentSearchCurrencyBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root

    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        currencyListView = binding.currencyListView
        searchView = binding.searchViewCurrency

        lifecycleScope.launch {

            val currenciesList = retrofit.getCurrencyList().currencies

            try {
                currencies = ArrayList(currenciesList.keys)

                listAdapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    requireContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    currencies
                )

                currencyListView.adapter = listAdapter
                currencyListView.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
                    Lists.currencyFrom = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
                }

                searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
                    override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                        if (currencies.contains(query)) {
                            listAdapter.filter.filter(query)
                            Lists.currencyFrom = query
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "No Currency found..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show()
                        }
                        return false
                    }

                    override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
                        listAdapter.filter.filter(newText)
                        return false
                    }
                })
            } catch (e: NullPointerException) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error..$e", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show()
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: DId you check the Raw response from API working fine On Physical Device?